# Close HTML page automatically after 5 seconds

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page which opens an HTML page on top of it or i should say it opens the html page on same browser tab. I want, when the html page loads the browser tab should automatically close after 5 seconds.

Comment: Are you using JS too? It's quite easy to achieve with JS.

Comment: I am not using JS, but i am open to use anything coding. Can you please tell me how to use JS in html to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Tried the onload event: it does not work, it executes immediately, even if you do a "setTimeout".

Turned out to be very simple, just add a script tag to your body:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
      window.close()
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

after it loads it executes the script and waits 5 seconds before it exits.

Comment: This is incorrect, you should remove the `()` after close. As is, it executes `window.close()` immediately

Answer (score 3):

You need JavaScript.
put some javascript code in your html that will open in new tab. then the code will wait for page to load and wait another 5 second to close the tab.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="waitFiveSec()"> <!--it will wait to load-->

<!-- your html... -->
<script>
  function waitFiveSec(){
    setTimeout(function, milliseconds) /*(here you need to implement delay code)*/
    window.close();
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is some links you may need :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

After some time, your page will auto closed.
You should try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout('window.location="/<!--Enter another page that will be opened after this page is closed-->"; ',3500<!--this is how long before it's closed-->);
    </script>
example:
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout('window.location="/Lab%20/index.php"; ',5000<!--this is how long before it's closed, 5000 for 5sec-->);
    </script>
```